# Error: "Can not implicitly convert type to unity.Quaternion"

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and am trying to rotate a cube but I get the error in the title

```
public Rigidbody rb;
public float rotate_speed;
public float rotatex = 0;
public float rotatey = 0;
public float rotatez = 0;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
    {
        rotatex += rotate_speed;
    }

    transform.rotation = (rotatex, rotatey, rotatez);
}
```

Comment: Here is the documentation that you should read: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-rotation.html

Answer (score 2):

Error doesn't have to do anything with unity. It is basics of programming.

Simply what it tells you is that you are trying to assign one object to another but those two have different types.

So let's break your code:

`Transform.rotation` is property in unity that is type of `Quaternion`. What you are trying to do is to set that property value to `(rotatex, rotatey, rotatez)`. What type is your value `(rotatex, rotatey, rotatez)`? - not Quaternion.

Now to simplify it let's say you declare variable like this:

```
int myVar;
```

You told that variable with name `myVar` is type of `int` (just like rotation is `Quaternion`).

Now when you try code like this:

```
myVar = "Something";
```

it will drop you error `Can not implicitly convert type to int` because you are trying to put `string` into place for `int`. You are trying to fit cube into space for square.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to prepend to your new values, `(rotatex, rotatey, rotatez)`, `new Quaternion`, that's how you fix the implicit conversion error but, to make a rotation, you might want to change your code completely to something like:

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
{
    transform.rotation *= Quaternion.Euler(rotate_speed, 0, 0);
}
```

This will rotate the object on the X axis the specified rotation speed, same can be done for Y and Z just place the `rotate_speed` in the appropriate spot in the `Euler` function.

Comment: This constructor is definitely not for creating a rotation ...

Comment: @Aybe while I don't see him asking about how to make a rotation, but rather why the implicit conversion exception has occurred, I have changed the code so it will make a rotation on the X axis, just like they wanted to do, sins they only change `rotatex` in their code.